Can my 2015 Corolla get a key fob?
I took my 2015 Toyota Corolla (trim S, the lowest trim) to my local dealership a few weeks ago to get a key and fob made.  They weren't able to work on it because of the CDK attack.  I did talk to the parts guy, though.  The info the parts guy was looking at seemed to indicate that my car may not have something about wireless key entry and therefore couldn't use a fob.  I called the dealership again today and they weren't able to tell me if my car could handle a fob without looking at it.  I don't want to spend the time to take it there without knowing:

Does anything need to be done before a fob and be programmed for it?
If something needs to be added to the car, can I do it myself for cheaper than the dealership?

Is there any way for me to know if my car can use a fob?  I expected this would be an easy question to answer.  If not, can I add that capability and how?
If it helps, I do have electronic locks; if I push the lock button on one door, all of the doors lock.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Was the car originally supplied with a key fob? If not, how do you expect it to be programmed, if the car was not set up for one? Or if you don't have a fob to copy. It may not even have key fob communication tech.

I bought it used and was not given a fob.  The whole question is how can I know whether it has key fob communication tech or if I can get it.

Your owner's manual implies that on models that originally came with a remote key fob, the trunk's key lock is omitted. So if your trunk has a key lock, my guess is that the car was never equipped with a remote opening RF receiver and programming a key fob won't result in keyless entry.

If you have electric door locks, you can install an aftermarket product for WAY less than the cost of a dealer doing anything to your car. Search online using "universal car door keyless entry".
